# "INVALID_LOGIN" Error message when upserting that only appears towards the end of each hour

Tags: apex, governorlimits, limits

So we've noticed that we're getting a lot of errors when trying to upsert data to SF, but always at the same time each hour:

[image]

The error confuses me:

"INVALID_LOGIN: Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out."

Why is this happening only at the end of the hour? Surely if the API user was locked out, it would stay locked out?

Does anyone have an explanation? I've been looking for hourly related limits and have only found:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_apicalls.htm

In there is "The limit is 3600 calls to login() per user per hour. Exceeding this limit results in a “Login Rate Exceeded” error."

But that isn't the error we're seeing here

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using a [connected app](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Connected_Apps) to login?

Comment: No we don't, we connect to the Salesforce SOAP API

Comment: Does your computer go to sleep at that exact time, you see the error in the logs?

Comment: Nope, the server is never shutdown

Comment: Do you see any errors in the Login History for the API user?

Comment: This is the strange thing, none whatsoever